# Check if input countains numbers in 2 fields in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

**So i recently tried to create a very simple calcylator in xcode**, the **problem** i have is when i press the calculate button when there is **no numbers** there the **app crashes**, and when i put anything that **isnt a number there and press the calculate button it also crash**, and i know it crash cause it cant convert nothing/non numbers into a double, but how do i check if it is **numbers** in the **textfields** and if it is it will **show the result off the
equation** and if there is no number it will just **set the textfeilds to nothing**
*(faktor1.text = "") (faktor2.text = "")*  ...

well it looks like this right now (ränka ut means calculate)

[image: nice]

here is the code i used,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var faktor1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var faktor2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var result: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var calculatebutton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var clearui: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    result.text = ""
    calculatebutton.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
    result.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
    clearui.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0
}

@IBAction func calculate( sender: Any) {

    let input1 = Double(faktor1.text!)!
    let input2 = Double(faktor2.text!)!

    let calculation = input1 * input2
    result.text = "(calculation)"
}

@IBAction func clearfnc( sender: Any) {
    result.text = ""
    faktor1.text = ""
    faktor2.text = ""
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply unwrap your optionals the Swift way, instead of using `!` (force unwrap)

This is an example using `guard`:

```
@IBAction func calculate(sender: Any) {
    guard
        let input1String = faktor1.text,
        let input2String = faktor1.text,
        let input1 = Double(input1String),
        let input2 = Double(input2String)
    else {
        faktor1.text = ""
        faktor1.text = ""
        return
    }

    let calculation = input1 * input2
    result.text = "\(calculation)"
}
```